# How to avoid overwriting of server.xml everytime after deployment in openshift tomcat

Tags: tomcat, https, openshift, server.xml

I am making some changes to the server.xml and context.xml for automatic redirection of http requests to https. Folder- repo/.openshift/config/

Source - [Openshift help](https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https) (goto-FOR TOMCAT (JBOSS EWS))

But everytime after git-push, when build and deployment takes place, these two files are refreshed and my changes are overwritten. How can I avoid the overwriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a .openshift directory on the gear itself, or a local .openshift directory in the root of your git repository?

If you place the server.xml and context.xml files in your local git repository, under .openshift/config/, then do your git add/commit/push, these files should end up in the proper place on the gear!

Comment: I don't know what was going wrong with sync of the .openshift directory from GIT, I cloned the repo, and now its working fine.